# Prepositions: ON the interview and FOR the interview?

Tags: prepositions

Do they convey same thing when I say,

Good luck **on** the interview?

*or*

Good luck **for** the interview?

Comment: I'd say "with the interview". Option 1 is ok but clunky, option 2 sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Either "with" or "in" works well, "for" doesn't, and "on" sounds somewhat odd to me. To be on the safe side, I'd use "with".

Comment: This answer could be improved with an Ngram or other evidence as to which forms are more prevalent.